# How to change the background color on a input checkbox with css?

Tags: css, html, checkbox, background-color

Hello Friends all I'm trying to do is change the background color of a checkbox. I tired many things but nothing works. Can some one help?

```
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      background: #3d404e;
      border: #7f83a2 1px solid;
   }
```

Comment: @DoughnutZombie, 1) yes, duplicate 2) no, looks like Ronny has another cause with his code, not background styling itself but border-styling missformatted, which breaks css verification