# Making break line without using <br/>

Tags: css, background-color, line-breaks

I want to display the first input[email] and my button in one line and make the rest in another line, Also want to disable default style for my checkbox and display it with transparent background.

```
<form method="post" name="form_BE_box" action="">
<input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Votre adresse mail" id="MAIL"/>
<button class="button" type="submit">S'inscrire</button><br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Partenaire" name="fou" /> Cochez ici pour s'inscrire aux communications partenaire
</form>
```

Comment: @VilleKoo I tried to make each block in span element and I apply the following css on after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}" but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your input into a div. Here is a working [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/krt9f8h1/3/).

And regarding the checkbox you can take a look at this answer: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css)

```html
<form method="post" name="form_BE_box" action="">
<input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Votre adresse mail" id="MAIL"/>
<button class="button" type="submit">S'inscrire</button>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Partenaire" name="fou" /> Cochez ici pour s'inscrire aux communications partenaire
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @vadber It helped me but I fixed my error like this <form style  ="display: block !important; " ..