# ngStyle with 'checked' state in ngFor loop

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a list of checkboxes that are asign to different departments(every department has it's own color) when box is unchecked only a border is in the color of department when checked backgroud is changed to the asign color [image: see pic]

box-shadow works how it should but can not make background to change (stayes blue-ish),
this is my code at the moment:

```
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let department of departments">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':checked===true? department.color:'white'}">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator" [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': '0 0 1px 1px' + department.color}" >  </span>
        <span class="custom-control-description text-capitalize">{{department.id}}</span>
      </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with angular.
You can't change the background color of checkboxes natively
you should use a custom class with pseudo elements :before and :after for changing the appearance of checkboxes and radio buttons

You have an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

well, I found a solution without using :before or :after which seams like a less of a hassle (in case someone searching for alternative solution):

```
 <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let department of departments">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (click)=gotChecked($event,customBox,department.color)>

        <span class="custom-control-indicator" [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': '0 0 1px 1px' + department.color}" >  </span>
        <span class="custom-control-indicator" #customBox></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description text-capitalize">{{department.id}}</span>
      </label>
```

and:

```
gotChecked($event: Event, customBox: HTMLSpanElement, color: string) {
let isChecked = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked
console.log(isChecked)
if (isChecked) {
  customBox.style.backgroundColor = color
} else {
  customBox.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
}
```

}