# how to change the background color of the input when checked?

Tags: css

```css
input:checked {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
input:not(:checked) + label {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="male" name="gender"> <label>Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"> <label>Female</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bike"> <label>I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Car"> <label>I have a car </label>
</form>
```

Here i have set of radio and checkbox inputs and i am trying to change the background color of the `checked` input. I'm able to alter the height and width of the element but not the `background-color` of the inputs.

Where am doing wrong?

Comment: [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```css
input:checked {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}

input:not(:checked) + label {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="male" name="gender"> <label>Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"> <label>Female</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bike"> <label>I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Car"> <label>I have a car </label>
</form>
```

Comment: this will change the label color only