# HTML Checkbox Style

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question about styling checkboxes. I have made one big table with checkboxes in it and would like to have each checkbox in that table to have its own color when checked, even better each row to have its own checked color. I have found a way to check them all at once with this

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

But I don't know how to use that so I color each row different or each one. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Give a class to each input and target it that way ? For example `<input class="checkbox-blue">` ?

Comment: If you want it to randomly set the color and the content is dynamic then you might need to use JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide on the algorithm how you want to differentiate the rows and add appropriate selector.

For example for coloring every other row differently:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Specific row with different color:

```css
tr:nth-child(7) input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 background-color: green;
}
```

You can learn more about `nth-child` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

The alternative is to use classes to target specific rows:

```css
.row-highlighted input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 background-color: orange;
}
```

Then you can apply and remove classes from rows to change their colors. You can have that logic in your templating engine or change that dynamicly with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

The **simplest** way to do this is giving a separate `class` to `<tr>` you are using in your `<table>` and then giving different colors to the `checkboxes` in each `<tr>` as follows;

```css
.row1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    outline:2px solid red;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.row2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    outline:2px solid green;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.row3 input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    outline:2px solid blue;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="check_boxes_colour.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table border="">
        <tr class="row1">
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row3">
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I used `outline` instead of `background-color` as more `css` is required to change `background-color` and its another [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css).

Comment: Why would you use ids instead of classes? Or if the order of colors is always the same `nth-child`? Ids have unnecessarily high specificity and should be unique which blocks you from reusing them.

Comment: @Kocik i edited my answer. I thought that your no. of rows in table is constant and you can't use same color twice. That why i used ids.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `JavaScript` and call the function on page load:

```
function setBgRandomColor() {    
   var
    r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    var randomColor = '#' +r+g+b;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').css('background', randomColor);
  }
```