# How to change checkbox background color?

Tags: html, css, material-components-web

I use [Material.io](https://material.io/develop/web/components) for my UI and create a check box:

```
<div class="mdc-form-field">
  <div class="mdc-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"
           class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"
           id="checkbox-1"/>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
           viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"
              fill="none"
              d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__ripple"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

Like this:

> https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/checkbox

How can I change checkbox background to other color for example red?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css

Comment: I use matrial.io components

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-checkbox#basic-usage

You need to change the color of `<div class="mdc-checkbox__background">`, you can do it via css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--mdc-theme-secondary:#ff0000` to change your color:

```
<div class="mdc-form-field">
  <div class="mdc-checkbox" style="--mdc-theme-secondary:#ff0000">
    <input type="checkbox"
           class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"
           id="checkbox-1"/>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
           viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"
              fill="none"
              d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__ripple"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They use another element in order to style the checkbox.

The element is: `<div class="mdc-checkbox__background">`

And the selector is this:
`.mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:checked ~ .mdc-checkbox__background, .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:indeterminate ~ .mdc-checkbox__background`

So all you need to do is to add this line on your style sheet:

```
.mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:checked ~ .mdc-checkbox__background, .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:indeterminate ~ .mdc-checkbox__background {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Hint: Use the dev tools on firefox or chrome. Right click on the element you want to check and then click on the `inspect` option.

Good luck and enjoy code!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SASS, you can use one of Material's Sass mixins (documentation found on [the same page linked in the question](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/checkboxes), at the bottom):

```
@import '@material/checkbox/mixins';

@include mdc-checkbox-container-colors($marked-fill-color: red);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google MDC version `11.0.0` you can use:

```css
.mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:not(:checked):not(:indeterminate):not([data-indeterminate=true]) ~ .mdc-checkbox__background {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mdc-checkbox__background {
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> It has its own classes for background like if you inspect and see the
>   structure of checkbox there is div on which
>   `.mdc-checkbox__background` class is present you can simple change with `!important` to override default

```
.mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:checked~.mdc-checkbox__background, .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:indeterminate~.mdc-checkbox__background {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the !important (:

Comment: @A.Meshu agree but in my case i use that inside component styles so need that along with `deep` selector :)