# How to add style CSS background-color in PHP echo?

Tags: php, html, css

Help me please.... I want to add a background color to PHP echo

My Script:

```
<div class="container">
    <input name='kursi[]' value='A1' id='A1' onclick='cer(this)' 
    autocomplete='off' type='checkbox' 
    <?php if(in_array(array('no_kursi_order' => 'A1'), $kursi))
      <!-- How to add style background-color here --> 
      {echo "disabled checked";
    } ?>>
    
    <label class='checkmark' for='A1'>A1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to add an html element like <p> or what do you need and add it a css rule with background color

Comment: How to? give me an example ... please

Comment: echo "disabled checked style=\"background-color:#f00;\" "; and remove html comment inside php tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <div class="container">
        <input name='kursi[]' value='A1' id='A1' onclick='cer(this)' 
        autocomplete='off' type='checkbox' 
        <?php if(in_array(array('no_kursi_order' => 'A1'), $kursi))
          <!-- How to add style background-color here --> 
-          {echo "disabled checked";
+          {echo "disabled checked style=\"background-color: red;\"";
        } ?>>
        
        <label class='checkmark' for='A1'>A1</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: @EdwinNick I have revise the issue, it seems like you are trying to change the background of the "input checkbox" in which cannot achieve by normal style only,

could check this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css

Comment: this link is correct ... I made it ... but what I want here: "Input checkbox" is clicked yellow after the data is inputted "Input checkbox" is disabled and red.

I applied this to "the application chooses seat tickets"

Can you help me?

Comment: could you provide a screenshot ?