# HTML Change the Background-Color of a Checked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I have a really simple question but I could'nt find  one simple answers for this.

I have a checkbox like below:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

And I want to change **just** the **background color** when this checkbox is checked.

Is there a simple way to do this in CSS  or JS ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color on a input checkbox with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css)

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw this question. Is there no way to do this on a leaner way?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo class and [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element to color your background when its checked.

Edit: For a complete background on a checkbox you we need full customised the checkbox. Its a complete CSS solution.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: this will change color of the text inside label and not the checkbox..

Comment: Yes like Simone say it's not that what I want

Comment: @NilsKyuubi Answer edited and working as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I edit the code of reference : [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css)
 this is the least you need to write:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: red;
  color: green;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
      <input type="checkbox" id="Custom" name="Custom">
      <label for="Custom">Custom Check</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Reference Link](http://jsfiddle.net/chimir/4dcLfm8b/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
header {
  background-color: #f39821;
  height: 150px;
}
.content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: -56px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}
.checkbox {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.checkbox__input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox__label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 28px;
}
.checkbox__label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) solid;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkbox__input:checked ~ .checkbox__label:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  background-color: #f3213d;
  border-color: #f3213d;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiPjx0aXRsZT51bnRpdGxlZDwvdGl0bGU+PHBhdGggZD0iTTAsMFYxSDFWMEgwWk0wLjQ1LDAuNzRsLTAuMDguMDhMMC4yOCwwLjc0LDAuMTQsMC42bDAuMDgtLjA4TDAuMzYsMC42NWwwLjQxLS40MUwwLjg2LDAuMzJaIi8+PC9zdmc+");
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiPjx0aXRsZT51bnRpdGxlZDwvdGl0bGU+PHBhdGggZD0iTTAsMFYxSDFWMEgwWk0wLjQ1LDAuNzRsLTAuMDguMDhMMC4yOCwwLjc0LDAuMTQsMC42bDAuMDgtLjA4TDAuMzYsMC42NWwwLjQxLS40MUwwLjg2LDAuMzJaIi8+PC9zdmc+");
}
.checkbox__input:disabled ~ .checkbox__label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.checkbox__input:disabled ~ .checkbox__label:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.checkbox__input:checked:disabled ~ .checkbox__label:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.checkbox__description {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  margin-left: 28px;
}
.checkbox__input ~ .checkbox__label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.checkbox__input:focus ~ .checkbox__label:after {
  -webkit-animation: click-wave .5s;
  animation: click-wave .5s;
}
.checkbox__input:checked ~ .checkbox__label:after {
  background-color: #f3213d;
}
.checkbox__input:not(:checked) ~ .checkbox__label:after {
  background-color: #000;
}
@-webkit-keyframes click-wave {
  0% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
@keyframes click-wave {
  0% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" checked="checked" class="checkbox__input">
    <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox__label">Checkbox 1</label>
    <div class="checkbox__description">Maecenas imperdiet dui velit, nec iaculis felis interdum nec.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox__input">
    <label for="checkbox-2" class="checkbox__label">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" checked="checked" class="checkbox__input" disabled>
    <label for="checkbox-3" class="checkbox__label">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="checkbox__input" disabled>
    <label for="checkbox-4" class="checkbox__label">Checkbox 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```